# Relation between Maven session and Maven phases?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

What is the relation between Maven session and Maven project? Does one session span one phase? Is there any document which details all this? Also I am trying to set a variable at runtime using my custom plugin in a module whose output is a jar. So should it be set in the session or in the project?

Comment: What exactly is a session?

Answer (score 1):

The `MavenSession` spans the entire build (`mvn` invocation), which may encompass multiple `MavenProject`s in a multi-module build. The build then goes through one or more phases, to which your custom plugin’s `<execution>` can be attached. Hope that explains things.